# Google app engine datastore "low level api" for Java examples, tutorials, documentation?

Tags: google-app-engine

Any suggestions on where to find examples, tutorials, and more thorough documentation on how to use the Google App Engine Datastore "Low Level Api" for Java?

I know this basic documentation page exists, but it just tells me whats in the Api and doesn't say much about how to actually use it:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/package-summary.html

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this [articles](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/datastore/overview.html) fit here, but covers in a very technical way the datastore.

Comment: That doesn't tell me how to use the low level API, but it definitely answered a crapload of other related questions that I had, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Two nice articles I found:

- [Introduction to working with App Engine’s low-level datastore API](http://ikaisays.com/2010/06/03/introduction-to-working-with-app-engine%E2%80%99s-low-level-datastore-api/) and
- [Issuing App Engine datastore queries with the Low-Level API](http://ikaisays.com/2010/07/13/issuing-app-engine-datastore-queries-with-the-low-level-api/)

Comment: After scratching my head for hours trying to figure out a what the  datastore really is, that first article explained it all !

Answer (score 1):

There are many pages at: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/

For example the following pages are all low-level API:

Entities,
Queries,
Transactions,
Metadata Queries,
Statistics,
Async API

Answer (score 1):

[Slim3](http://sites.google.com/site/slim3appengine/#gtx) is supposed to be a thin wrapper around the low level datastore.

Since this is open source,  you could either study it for the code or as a wrapper.